# Bitbake file not showing

Tags: file-upload, rules, bitbake, udev

Trying to have a udev rules file added on reboot/built into an image as well. New to bitbake/udev so correct(sorry) my verbage if needed.

I'm not seeing my file in its path after booting on my image.

.bb file context:

```
FILESEXTRAPATHS_prepend := "${THISDIR}/files:"
SRC_URI = "file://83-duplicate_dev.rules"
do_install() {
  install -D -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/83-duplicate_dev.rules ${D}${sysconfdir}/udev/rules.d/83-duplicate_dev.rules
```

This is the only file I think I'm having problems with, I did a similar .bb file earlier and everything worked. I'm thinking the path may not be created yet? Not sure if I need to create that.

Answer (score 0):

Packaging stage need to know which file need to be installed in respective package.

Please try adding this to your recipe:

```
FILES_${PN} += "/etc/udev/rules.d/83-duplicate_dev.rules"
```